# How to run enough cycles of $digest until everything is $compiled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using `$compile` in directive of AngularJS, in order to dynamically decide which template to use, mainly in order to improve performance.

Also, I need to do something on the compiled HTML. As a `$digest` loop is needed after `$compile`, so I put it after a `$timeout`, and it works.

```
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
  // Get html code
  var e = $compile(html)(scope);
  element.replaceWith(e);
  $timeout().then(function() {
    // Do something with compiled HTML
  });
}
```

However, if there're cascaded directives using this pattern, more than 1 time of `$digest` has to been executed.

So, is there a way, to run `$digest` loops until it is "fully" compiled? Thank you.

```
// Original HTML, foo and bar will be replaced
<foo>
  <bar>
  </bar>
</foo>

// After 1 loop of digest, partially compiled
<foo-compiled>
  <bar>
  </bar>
</foo-compiled>

// After 2 loop of digest, fully compiled (Desired result)
<foo-compiled>
  <bar-compiled>
  </bar-compiled>
</foo-compiled>
```